What's the difference between primary, secondary, simplex and duplex nozzles, especially in a PT6?
I'm confused about the difference between the nozzles and the PT6A-114 engine manual is of no help.

Primary vs secondary
When the engine is started:

Fuel is initially distributed to only some nozzles, known as the primary nozzles.

When N1 has reached some threshold, fuel is also distributed to the rest of the nozzles, the secondary nozzles.


In this scheme all nozzles, primary and secondary, have a single orifice (simplex nozzles).

The dual manifold assembly consists of 14 fuel manifold adapters (seven primary, six secondary and one secondary inlet adapter) each of which incorporates a simplex fuel nozzle. (Source: PT6 Training Manual).

The sequence is managed by the Fuel Control Unit and the Starting Flow Control.
Simplex vs duplex
A simplex fuel nozzle has one orifice, a duplex nozzle has two orifices:

Duplex nozzle on the left, simplex on the right (source). Duplex nozzle from the PT6 Training Manual:

Using duplex nozzles, the starting sequence is different, all nozzles are fed, but:

Only one orifice is used before N1 threshold (primary flow)
The second orifice is used after N1 threshold (secondary flow).

This way all nozzles are always used, the fuel spray pattern and the flame are more homogeneous in the annular combustor.
